# Reading XML in Java Applet

Tags: java, xml, applet

I know:

- I have to sign the applet so it can read files
- How to parse XML files

My Questions would be:

- Should I keep the XML file in the .jar or separate?
- Are there some best practices tutorials? if so please link me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ship your XML with the applet, then you won't need to sign it, as you're not really reading files, but just loading additional resources.

Only *you* can answer where the XML should be, because we don't know what it's used for, how often it changes and if its the same for every user of your applet.